# First Posts Review Queues: When are these posts no longer sent for moderation?

Tags: support, review

From reading this [post](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) on the review queues, I now understand how they work in general. However, the answer's author mentions

> The First Posts queue contains the **first few posts** asked by new users (who will probably need help learning to use the site)

Does that mean a user would have to reach a certain level of reputation until her questions/answers no longer appear in the review queue? What would be this level of reputation be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When selecting items for the First Post Review queue, we don't look at the reputation of the user on the post.  There are a variety of requirements for the queue but that main one is based on whether or not it is the first question or first answer by a user.

If it's their first post, then it is eligible for review.

Comment: Note that this also mean that if your first post was deleted for any reason, the system will take your second post as your first.