# Why are there no review tasks generated for a couple of my recent First Posts on a site?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, new-users

Last Sunday, I've asked two questions, one on [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) and one on [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/). Yesterday, I've also answered a question on [Role-Playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/). As far as I know, those were my first posts on said sites. (I could be mistaken and have posted a now-deleted post, but on three sites, that's rather unlikely.)

I was curious how they have been reviewed. However, looking at the timeline of each of these posts, I can't find an entry for a First Posts review. It's not that these are hidden for you as author of the post, since I do see them for my first posts on Stack Overflow and Ask Different. The First Posts review queues on those sites are empty now (even when opened from a private window), and meanwhile there have been other first posts reviewed on at least the DIY and RPG sites.

So I assume the review tasks weren't generated in the first place. My question is: why? I did already have some contribution on those sites in the form of suggested edits. According to [@Taryn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280142/295232), that shouldn't matter:

> If it's their first post, then it is eligible for review.

I *have* 'created' tag wiki excerpts on all three sites (the Community Building one is now orphaned) - would that be the cause? In those cases ([example](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/116576/revisions)) the Community user is listed as the creator of the first (empty) revision.

Comment: Hmm... AFAIK, even if the user has deleted posts, as long as it's the "first" post seen by the regular users, it should enter the First Posts Review Queue too. Also, I believe that tag excerpt & wiki creation is always owned by the Community user, so it shouldn't affect your First Posts status either...

Comment: Yes, I'm just fishing for possible causes.

Comment: As a moderator on a different site, I have noticed that it can take 15 minutes for a review queue to be updated with a specific review.

Comment: I'm limited access at CB but a *far reaching* (?) theory is that it's not your 'first' post since [you've edited](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1297) long ago and had it approved. Another possibility (and possibly in combination with) is that you have a Diamond. I've discussed this with a couple of people, but for *some* people (Mod Tool access, Staff Bit, other) sometimes things don't work exactly the same. For example I can do 'something' and suffer no penalty from the software, whereas when 'something else' happens I get a 'helicopter parent pop-up'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Community user is the creator of the tag in that scenario. It looks like those tag wiki edits are what's preventing your Q&A posts from landing in review. It's an easy fix, but I'm going to ask around if this is intended behavior or an oversight since I'm honestly not sure off the top of my head.

**Update:** It was an oversight after all. Going forward, only question and answer posts will be checked. Here's the review history on [one of your posts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/93979), for example.

Thanks for the report!